# error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘{anonymous}::ELFSparcAsmBackend’ in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

How to fix this issue? While building LLVM 15.0.2?

```
/CCR-master/llvm/lib/Target/Sparc/MCTargetDesc/SparcAsmBackend.cpp:375:65: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘{anonymous}::ELFSparcAsmBackend’
   return new ELFSparcAsmBackend(T, STI.getTargetTriple().getOS());
```

Comment: The error message is rather clear, the `ELFSparcAsmBackend` class is *abstract*. I.e. it has some pure virtual functions. You need to use or create an instance of a class that inherits from the `ELFSparcAsmBackend` class and implements those functions.

Comment: `ELFSparcAsmBackend` is not abstract in the upstream sources tagged for 15.0.2. Follow the instructions on building LLVM with Cmake exactly and make sure that you don't accidentally modified any file. And if LLVM does not build following the instructions on a supported platform, then you should file a bug report with LLVM. Asking here isn't going to help you.

Comment: I've edited in different portions of LLVM. But not in SparcAsmBackend or AVRAsmBackend but in the target directory they are throwing many such errors like the mentioned one.